# Not full width toolbar in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, toolbar

I am using Toolbar in my app and I custom the TextView to the center of the Toolbar but it not full width of the screen of toolbar and remain a little screen at the left side like the picture below. So how can I do to make the Custom TextView to the center of the screen and Toolbar?

**My current screen problem :**

[image]

**The screen I want :**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="#F00"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Thank!

Comment: post your code , xml file

Comment: Remove any left padding that you have given to the toolbar.

Comment: I removed all padding

Comment: Your toolbar has full width, red colored element is your text view.

Comment: yes @Kaushal28 my text view is red color

Comment: your textview has text `title`, but in image it is hello? What is wrong with it?

Comment: ohhh I used setText("hello") to set that title. I test it. @Kaushal28

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `ToolBar` add below property to remove Left Padding.

```
 app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
 app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: It worked properly!